# CSS width properties not working correctly

Tags: html, css

I write a html page containing a header on top, following by a section part and an aside part, and then a footer part, and write some CSS codes for styling. here is the html and CSS code:

```css
body{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: peachpuff;
}


header, section, aside, footer, article{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border: 1px solid cadetblue;
    font-size: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header>h1{

    height: 100px;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red;
}
article {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
section{
    width: 60%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-right:3px;
display: inline-block;
    /*float:left;*/
}

aside{
    width: 37%;
    margin-left:3px;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

footer{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1>This is header.</h1>
</header>

<section>
    this is section.
    <article>this is article.</article>
</section>

<aside>aside part.</aside>

<footer>this is footer.</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I set **width:100%** for header and footer, and it should make then to stretch so fill all the body width, as body is their parent node. but I notice that it cause header and footer that go beyond the body width at right side! if I comment that, every thing will be fine, but why it doesn't work as expected?

and second question, I want section and aside to be located next to each other, and by setting **float:right;** for aside tag they are, but if I set **float:left;** for section element too, while they still are next to each other, footer become their background too! why that happens?

thanks.

Comment: the `margin`  make's the header push himself out of the body

Comment: @ Ramon de Vries - but i set box-sizing: border-box; so it margin couldn't cause that, isn't it?

Comment: try my answer, that might be working for you

Comment: The **default** is width `auto` because they are *block level* elements. **No need** to set width to `100%`.

Comment: @vsync - you're right, but why setting width cause this issue? actually it should has no effect, but it has!

Comment: @feelfree - you are wrong saying it shouldn't have an effect. it **should**! This is the most basic, fundamental CSS. It goes *outside* because you have margin on the left & right sides... it pushes the `<header>` element outside of the `<body>` element for that reason..

Answer (score 3):

The `margin:10px;` will push the header out of the `body`, remove the `margin` from the header and it works fine.

```css
body{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: peachpuff;
}


header, section, aside, footer, article{
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border: 1px solid cadetblue;
    font-size: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header>h1{

    height: 100px;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red;
}
article {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
section{
    width: 60%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-right:3px;
display: inline-block;
    /*float:left;*/
}

aside{
    width: 37%;
    margin-left:3px;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

footer{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1>This is header.</h1>
</header>

<section>
    this is section.
    <article>this is article.</article>
</section>

<aside>aside part.</aside>

<footer>this is footer.</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, it works, but i set box-sizing: border-box for all elements, so why still margin change the dimensions of the boxes?

Comment: @feelfree, `https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp` box-sizing will only affect the padding on elements, not the margin

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: peachpuff;
}


header, section, aside, footer, article{
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border: 1px solid cadetblue;
    font-size: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header>h1{

    height: 100px;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red;
}
article {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
section{
    width: 60%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-right:3px;
display: inline-block;
    /*float:left;*/
}

aside{
    width: 37%;
    margin-left:3px;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

footer{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1>This is header.</h1>
</header>

<section>
    this is section.
    <article>this is article.</article>
</section>

<aside>aside part.</aside>

<footer>this is footer.</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want like this?